# propagate dependencies to header-only ExternalProject with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, guideline-support-library

I'm trying to build a header-only library using CMake ([Microsoft/GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL)), in such a way that I can use variables like `GSL_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `GSL_LIBRARIES` to link to the target and propagate the appropriate dependencies.

The project I'm working on has a TON of sub-directories, and all the external projects are built in their own sub-directories, hence why the variables are important.

I'm using CMake 3.2.3

Typically (for a library with an actual .lib or .a) I'd do something like:

```
SET(TARGET_NAME gsl)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
    ${TARGET_NAME}-ext
    URL "http://target/url"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)   # download/unzip the header-only project

# Specify include dir
SET(${TARGET_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include CACHE STRING "${TARGET_NAME} include directory")

# Library
add_library(${TARGET_NAME} SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES 
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "some/path/to/some/lib"
)
add_dependencies(${TARGET_NAME} ${TARGET_NAME}-ext)
SET(${TARGET_NAME}_LIBRARIES ${TARGET_NAME} CACHE STRING "${TARGET_NAME} library location")

MARK_AS_ADVANCED(${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_DIR ${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_INCLUDE_DIRS ${TARGET_NAME_UPPER}_LIBRARIES)
```

The problem here is that the header-only library has no lib to set the imported path for, so I can't use an `IMPORTED` library. If I don't use a library at all, then I can't set the dependencies in other modules on GSL without building (i.e. downloading/unzipping) *every single time*, which I don't want to do. a `custom_target` would have the same problem, so that's a no-go.

I think what I want is an interface library, something like

```
add_library(${TARGET_NAME} INTERFACE)
add_dependencies(${TARGET_NAME} ${TARGET_NAME}-ext)
```

but then cmake complains that

> CMake Error at 3rdParty/gsl/CMakeLists.txt:33 (add_dependencies):
>     add_dependencies Cannot add target-level dependencies to INTERFACE library
>     target "gsl".

Is there someway I can use the interface library (or something) to propagate the dependency on the external project?

Comment: Please clarify: "build a header-only library", because there are not build to a .lib, .so or .dll file. Use them directly or set the appropriate include path.

Comment: @knivil I updated the question title to remove the word 'build'. That said, I think it's relatively clear in the question that I want to use cmake to download/unzip the header-only library, but in such a way that it only invokes the external project if the dependencies require it to.

Comment: The error message for the imported library looks bogus. Does your cmake version actually support INTERFACE libraries? What is the value of TARGET_NAME?

Comment: @pmr updated the question with the actual target name and the full error message. It's not bogus. I'm using cmake version 3.2.3, and from what I understand interface libraries were introduced in 3.0.0.

Comment: Furthermore I'm lost what the purpose of the add_dependencies call is. A INTERFACE library can't have a dependency because there is nothing to do for it anyway.

Comment: OK, I get it now. You need it to trigger the download of the library for ExternalProject. Sounds like a valid use case and the restriction on the INTERFACE target feels somewhat artificial. Maybe ask the ML and request the feature.

Comment: @pmr my project is composed of many 3rd party dependencies, libraries and executables, all of which can be built independently. I need to be able to hang a dependency on gsl to targets which need those headers to be available, so that something actually causes gsl to be downloaded and unzipped, prior to building things which consume it.

Comment: @pmr Because of your intuition that the error seemed bogus, I got 3.4.3 and tried it and it worked as expected. Apparently it was a bug/oversight that was fixed in 3.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disallowing dependencies on `INTERFACE` libraries was [an oversight that was corrected in CMake version 3.3](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15414). After upgrading to the latest-stable release, I was able to use the methodology described in the question, and it worked exactly as desired.